# Unity proguard: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, duplicates, proguard

I am Using Unity 2018.1.6f1 with Google Play Services and Startapp sdk. Now I need to integrate Admob. But I am not able to make a build.

I switched to Proguard in build settings since I faced DEX limiattion and it was advised by Admob.

Snippet of Unity console message:

```
stderr[
Note: there were 269 duplicate class definitions.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
```

And then long list of 
    Note: duplicate definition of program class

How shall I modify 'mainTemplate.gradle' or 'proguard-user.txt' files to make the build? Or shall I?

Answer (score 0):

when you build for release with minify enabled you need to put exceptions in your proguard file. These exceptions are totally dependent on the implementations you use in the app build gradle file.  As an example, this implementation:

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

//added these 2 lines to remove All com.android.support libraries must use the exact
// same version specification warning; from 26 to 28
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'

// Google
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'


// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'


// Firebase UI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

// firebase needs this needs to be version 1.1.1 firebase depends on
// a mismatch - 1.0.0 & 1.1.1
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

// retrofit, gson
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'

//from the quick start
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services- 
sheets:v4-rev553-1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
```

Needs this in the proguard file to build a release:

```
 # my stuff below
 -dontnote retrofit2.Platform
 # Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be 
  used at runtime.
 -dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
 # Retain generic type information for use by reflection by 
 converters and adapters.
 #-keepattributes Signature
 # Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy 
 instance.
 #-keepattributes Exceptions

 -dontwarn okio.**

 # Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and 
 @Key annotations accessed via reflection
 -keepclassmembers class * {
 @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
 }

 #-keepattributes 
 Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

 #-dontnote org.apache.**
 #-dontwarn java.lang.**

 -dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**

 -keep public class com.google.common.** { public *; }
 -dontwarn com.google.common.**

 -dontnote android.net**
 -dontwarn com.google.firebase.appindexing.internal.**
```

So the thing to do is find the duplicates and wirnings in the log and add a proguard entry for each warning in the log

Comment: Here's my console error:
`stderr[
Note: there were 269 duplicate class definitions.

    Execution failed for task 
    ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    ]
    stdout[
    Note: duplicate definition of program class 
    [com.google.android.gms.actions.ItemListIntents]`

And here's my proguard-user.txt:
`-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**`

But still I get an error

Comment: any one of the 269 duplicate class definitions could cause it to fail; you may need more in your proguard file.

Comment: I've added all of the warning files to the proguard file like this `-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.common.zza` but no effect

Comment: If the error NEVER changes as 'no effect' implies maybe gradle is looking in the wrong place for the proguard file.  put this in as a test only# bad
#-ignorewarnings
#-keep class * {
#    public private *;
#}